# Can I use my Logitech G5 with a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, g5

Just ordered a MacBook Pro. Having never had one or used one I am unsure if my mouse will work.

Can I use my Logitech G5 with a MacBook Pro?

Comment: The [Logitec support site](http://support.logitech.com/software/logitech-control-center-for-macintosh-os-x) says: **Yes!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not especially familiar with that model of mouse, but almost all, if not all, peripherals like mice and keyboards will work with the Mac. Even if Mac compatibility isn't listed for the mouse, it still might work.

Comment: Okay thanks. I just saw the magic mouse on Amazon so was wondering if I needed to buy it!

Comment: @GreenRails I think you'll find that you'll like the Magic Trackpad even better than a mouse.